# Add MySQL entry from PHP web page

Tags: php, mysql, forms, web

I am developing a web application that allows a user to add entries to a MySQL database through a web form. The web form posts to the same page, some PHP code captures that data and sends it to MySQL. For whatever reason, nothing ever makes it to MySQL. This is the code I have so far that isn't working:

```
    <?php
    include("config.inc.php");
    $Name=$_POST['AddName'];
    $Group=$_POST['AddGroup'];
    $Grade=$_POST['AddGrade'];
    $Position=$_POST['AddPosition'];
    $Email=$_POST['AddEmail'];
    $HomeAddress=$_POST['AddHomeAddress'];
    $City=$_POST['AddCity'];
    $State="SC";
    $Zip=$_POST['AddZIP'];
    $CellPhone=$_POST['AddCellNumber'];
    $HomePhone=$_POST['AddHomeNumber'];
    $FirstPeriod=$_POST['AddFirstPeriod'];
    $SecondPeriod=$_POST['AddSecondPeriod'];
    $ThirdPeriod=$_POST['AddThirdPeriod'];
    $FourthPeriod=$_POST['AddFourthPeriod'];
    $FifthPeriod=$_POST['AddFifthPeriod'];
    $SixthPeriod=$_POST['AddSixthPeriod'];
    $SeventhPeriod=$_POST['AddSeventhPeriod'];
    $Homeroom=$_POST['AddHomeroom'];
    $dbpassword=$_POST['AddPassword'];

    $con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","$username","******");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die();
      }        

    mysql_select_db("$database", $con);
    $sql="INSERT INTO names     (Name,Grp,Grade,Position,Email,HomeAddress,City,State,Zip,CellPhone,HomePhone,FirstPeriod,SecondPeriod,ThirdPeriod,FourthPeriod,FifthPeriod,SixthPeriod,SeventhPeriod,Homeroom)
    VALUES('$Name','$Group','$Grade','$Position','$Email','$HomeAddress,'$City','$State','$Zip','$CellPhone','$HomePhone','$FirstPeriod','$SecondPeriod','$ThirdPeriod','$FourthPeriod','$FifthPeriod','$SixthPeriod','$SeventhPeriod','$Homeroom')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
      {
      die();
      }
    echo "1 record added";

    mysql_close($con)
    ?>
            </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Advice: Ross read about the sql injection

Comment: Second advice: NEVER leave password when you post the code!

Comment: echo some error messages with your `die()`s, and you might get a clue what went wrong...

Comment: And this will be internal only, so I am really not that concerned with SQL injection.

Comment: Ross, please be aware that the password is still visible in the edit history. You may be better off deleting this question and starting over, or at the very least, change your password now.

Comment: Again, not accessible from the internet, but I have now changed the password as you requested. Thanks.

Comment: @Ross: And what happens later when this becomes accessible from the internet (or from another internal server, or whatever). Bad practices are bad practices - get in the habit of doing it right in the first place. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and see what it says:

```
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: That helped a lot. Something wrong with my SQL string.
        `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'City','SC','ZIP','Cell','Home','First','Second','Third','Fourth','Fifth','Sixth'' at line 2 `

Comment: Your `'$HomeAddress` is missing a single-quote. Should be `'$HomeAddress'`

Comment: Still the same error even with fixes (except for excape_string) suggested below.

Comment: I keep missing these additional comments. Grr Chrome. Trying that now.

Comment: YAY! That fixed it!! THANK YOU SO MUCH! :) Now to implement the escape_string method to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting `echo mysql_error();`. This should give you at least a starting place to where your query is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_close($con)` should have a semi-colon at the end.

check your log for errors.

use `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: Semicolon didn't fix it. And oddly enough, there aren't any MySQL errors in the logs at all pertaining to this. What else should I try?

Comment: I just tried the escape string and that killed the form. My error log is filled with this now:

`[Tue Nov 15 19:05:36 2011] [error] [client XX.XX.XX.XX] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: AddSixthPeriod in /var/www/<REDACTED>/directory/dbadd2.php on line 25, referer: http://<REDACTED>/directory/dbadd.php`
         `[Tue Nov 15 19:05:36 2011] [error] [client XX.XX.XX.XX] PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user '<REDACTED>'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /var/www/<REDACTED>/directory/dbadd2.php on line 25, referer: http://<REDACTED>/directory/dbadd.php`

Answer (score 0):

PHP hides errors. To debug, start by placing these two lines as the first lines within the `<?php` tag

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Also in case the error was in mysql you can do:

`print_r(mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SHOW WARNINGS", $con)));`

or

`print_r(mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SHOW ERRORS", $con)));`

Directly after the mysql query you think may have failed.

Answer (score 0):

change your database selection to

```
mysql_select_db("database name")
```

or

```
mysql_select_db($database);
```

your are trying to select a database named "$database" with a dollar sign as a string, not the name in that variable.
also, use

mysql_real_escape_string($sql) to escape those variables.(avoiding sql injecion) you can find links about it in other comments.

Comment: Thanks for the escape_string tip. Will change it.

Comment: And the $database is a variable pulled from config.inc.php.

Answer (score 0):

`die(mysql_error());`
will fix it.
Also have a look at escaping. It would be very easy to inject into the current code.

If you are not going to escape (I don't know when you would do that) you might as well use the `$_POST` rather than assigning to a variable and using the variable.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$sql="INSERT INTO names     (Name,Grp,Grade,Position,Email,HomeAddress,City,State,Zip,CellPhone,HomePhone,FirstPeriod,SecondPeriod,ThirdPeriod,FourthPeriod,FifthPeriod,SixthPeriod,SeventhPeriod,Homeroom)
    VALUES('$Name','$Group','$Grade','$Position','$Email','$HomeAddress,'$City','$State','$Zip','$CellPhone','$HomePhone','$FirstPeriod','$SecondPeriod','$ThirdPeriod','$FourthPeriod','$FifthPeriod','$SixthPeriod','$SeventhPeriod','$Homeroom')";
```

to

```
$sql="INSERT INTO names     (Name,Grp,Grade,Position,Email,HomeAddress,City,State,Zip,CellPhone,HomePhone,FirstPeriod,SecondPeriod,ThirdPeriod,FourthPeriod,FifthPeriod,SixthPeriod,SeventhPeriod,Homeroom)
    VALUES('$Name','$Group','$Grade','$Position','$Email','$HomeAddress','$City','$State','$Zip','$CellPhone','$HomePhone','$FirstPeriod','$SecondPeriod','$ThirdPeriod','$FourthPeriod','$FifthPeriod','$SixthPeriod','$SeventhPeriod','$Homeroom')";
```

Comment: have you tried the above code, it fixes the problem in the question